# Update records in a select query with different values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have an INSERT INTO query that works great to create child records when a parent record is added.  I basically need to run the same thing but instead of adding new child records, I need to update the column that contains a sum value.

As an example, I have the following data.  Shift_Roster_ID is the PK for the first table.  RosterID and ShiftID are both foreign keys.  For ShiftID=1, I want to update the ShiftCount for each unique RosterID.  The ShiftCount is the sum of the Response values for any shift for which the PeriodID in the second table matches the PeriodID of ShiftID=1.

```
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| Shift_Roster_ID | RosterID | ShiftID | ShiftCount | Response |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 1               | 1        | 1       | 0          | 1        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2               | 2        | 1       | 0          | 3        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 3               | 3        | 1       | 0          | 8        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 4               | 1        | 2       | 0          | 1        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 5               | 2        | 2       | 0          | 8        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 6               | 3        | 2       | 0          | 7        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 7               | 1        | 2       | 0          | 7        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 8               | 2        | 3       | 0          | 7        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 9               | 3        | 3       | 0          | 6        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+

+---------+----------+
| ShiftID | PeriodID |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 1        |
+---------+----------+
| 2       | 1        |
+---------+----------+
| 3       | 2        |
+---------+----------+
```

The result should be

```
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| Shift_Roster_ID | RosterID | ShiftID | ShiftCount | Response |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 1               | 1        | 1       | **2**      | 1        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2               | 2        | 1       | **11**     | 3        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 3               | 3        | 1       | **15**     | 8        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 4               | 1        | 2       | 0          | 1        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 5               | 2        | 2       | 0          | 8        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 6               | 3        | 2       | 0          | 7        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 7               | 1        | 2       | 0          | 7        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 8               | 2        | 3       | 0          | 7        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 9               | 3        | 3       | 0          | 6        |
+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you start with a simpler problem? See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry...my apologies.  I'm new to this process but I see your point.  I'm happy to share the source data as it's all test data anyway at this point but to post it would be rather lengthy.  I'll see if I can come up with a more general way to ask the question so the solution will be more widely useful for everyone.  I'll work on it and edit the original post.

Comment: I just don't think you need more than two tables in order to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Updated original post to simplify the question (hopefully).

Comment: Please post your final expected result.

Comment: Final result added to post.

Comment: I am probably the only one who doesn't understand, but I will ask anyway. What is a `shift`? And can you qualify the columns `PerioID` and `ShiftID` mentioned in the following sentence with their table names? `The ShiftCount is the sum of the Response values for any shift for which the PeriodID in the second table matches the PeriodID of ShiftID=1.`

Comment: The application is for filling shifts of overtime.  I also have table for different time periods (such as First half of 2019, second half 2019, first half 2020, and so on) as well as a table for data related to each shift.  The PeriodID and ShiftID relate back to those tables but that data is irrelevant to this query.

Comment: @ronaldaaronson Some people work regular jobs in offices (typically from 9-5, Monday to Friday). Other jobs (like restaurants, bars, and call centres) require longer hours so they need some people to work in the morning, some people in the afternoon, and some people at night - usually with some overlap between them. These are 'shifts'.

Comment: @Strawberry I am sorry you had to go through such a long explanation as I do understand 'shift' in that sense (English is my mother tongue). I thought perhaps the OP was using 'shift' to refer to one of the tables.